# how to decrypt magento dataencrypted

Tags: php

i want to decrypt magento data using the data encrypted and config key to show the data as plan test

i tried alotof ways but no one has done with me is there any way

i mean is there any way as php script to do it

and thanks

i used this code i found here but doesn't show anything

```
<?php

class Encryption
{
    const CIPHER = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128; // Rijndael-128 is AES
    const MODE   = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;

    /* Cryptographic key of length 16, 24 or 32. NOT a password! */
    private $key;
    public function __construct($key) {
        $this->key = $key;
    }

    public function encrypt($plaintext) {
        $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(self::CIPHER, self::MODE);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($ivSize, MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);
        $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(self::CIPHER, $this->key, $plaintext, self::MODE, $iv);
        return base64_encode($iv.$ciphertext);
    }

    public function decrypt($ciphertext) {
        $ciphertext = base64_decode($ciphertext);
        $ivSize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(self::CIPHER, self::MODE);
        if (strlen($ciphertext) < $ivSize) {
            throw new Exception('Missing initialization vector');
        }

        $iv = substr($ciphertext, 0, $ivSize);
        $ciphertext = substr($ciphertext, $ivSize);
        $plaintext = mcrypt_decrypt(self::CIPHER, $this->key, $ciphertext, self::MODE, $iv);
        return rtrim($plaintext, "\0");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In simplest case, when we use all of standard Magento settings:

1. Encryptor get from model core/encryption,
2. Key from setting global/crypt/key
3. Using Mcrypt
4. With standard cipher MCRYPT_BLOWFISH and mode MCRYPT_MODE_ECB 
   (all given for Magento 1.8.1)

```
$encrypted  = 'R4VQyYn6JHs='; 
$key = '370ee4d319aebb395b982d72190588d2';
$cipher = MCRYPT_BLOWFISH;
$mode = MCRYPT_MODE_ECB;

$handler = mcrypt_module_open($cipher, '', $mode, '');
$initVector = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($handler), MCRYPT_RAND);
mcrypt_generic_init($handler, $key, $initVector);


var_dump(str_replace("\x0", '', trim(mdecrypt_generic($handler, base64_decode($encrypted)))));
```

However, I can't see a point in using this, since you can use Magento, and just call

```
Magento::helper('core')->decrypt($encrypted);
```